# What is the difference between .subscribe and .drive

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

I am quite new in Reactive Programming, Here is what I'm trying

**.drive**

```
searchController.rx.text
        .asDriver()
        .drive(onNext: { (element) in
            print(element)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**.subscribe**

```
searchController.rx.text
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { (element) in
            print(element)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

both blocks are working exactly the same, What is the purpose of using `.drive` over `.subscribe`? In which scenario we should use `.drive` over `.subscribe` ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Driver` is a bit different from `Observable`. From documentation:

> Trait that represents observable sequence with following properties:
>
> - it never fails
> - it delivers events on `MainScheduler.instance`
> - `share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)` sharing strategy

I assume that `searchController.rx.text` never fails and `share` isn't required in this situation.

So we have only one point that makes them different in your situation:

> - it delivers events on `MainScheduler.instance`

And you can check it yourself. Before `subscribe` insert this and your events won't be delivered on main thread:

```
.observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
```

That is how I checked it in my code:

```
something
    .asObservable()
    .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        print("observable is on main thread: ", Thread.isMainThread)
    })

something
    .asDriver()
    .drive(onNext: { _ in
        print("driver is on main thread: ", Thread.isMainThread)
    })
```

Logs:

> driver is on main thread: **true**
>
> observable is on main thread: **false**

**In which scenario we should use `.drive`**:

When working with **UI**. Why? From documentation:

> Important
>
> Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main
> dispatch queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction
> particularly applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that
> involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.